# Read JSON file to pandas dataframe - ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am trying to read JSON file using pandas:

```
import json

with open("data.json", "r") as read_file:
    data = pd.read_json(read_file)
data
```

this is a sample of JSON file. it is a large JSON file.

```
 'terms': 'https://open.fda.gov/terms/', 'license': 'https://open.fda.gov/license/', 'last_updated': '2021-06-24', 'results': {'skip': 24000, 'limit': 12000, 'total': 51909}},
 'results': [{'receiptdateformat': '102', 'receiver': None, 'companynumb': 'USA040258482', 'receivedateformat': '102', 'primarysource': {'qualification': '1'}, 'transmissiondateformat': '102', 'fulfillexpeditecriteria': '2', 'safetyreportid': '4338993-3', 'sender': {'senderorganization': 'FDA-Public Use'}, 'receivedate': '20040329', 'patient': {'patientonsetage': '12', 'patientonsetageunit': '801', 'reaction': [{'reactionmeddrapt': 'CHEST PAIN'}], 'drug': [{'drugcharacterization': '1', 'medicinalproduct': 'STRATTERA', 'drugauthorizationnumb': '21411', 'drugadministrationroute': '048', 'drugindication': 'ATTENTION DEFICIT/HYPERACTIVITY DISORDER', 'openfda': {'application_number': ['NDA021411'], 'brand_name': ['STRATTERA'], 'generic_name': ['ATOMOXETINE HYDROCHLORIDE'], 'manufacturer_name': ['Eli Lilly and Company'], 'product_ndc': ['0002-3227', '0002-3238', '0002-3228', '0002-3229', '0002-3239', '0002-3250', '0002-3251'], 'product_type': ['HUMAN PRESCRIPTION DRUG']
```

I am getting an error

```
ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.
```

How do I get this right?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample of Json file that causes the problem?

Comment: I have addaed a sample